Capacitor SQLite Web: Error: Run: ExecSet: in saveToStore SetDBToStore: undefined
I am currently facing a problem with the Capacitor Community Sqlite Library with Angular Ionic, on desktop web (Chrome used as browser).
@capacitor-community/sqlite
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/sqlite
The difficult thing is that the error only occurs roughly 1% of the time (1 in 100 times). It's really hard to reproduce. It might be some sort of race condition triggering in my app.
I sometimes get this error after I refresh my page in the browser:
Error: Run: ExecSet: in saveToStore SetDBToStore: undefined

so this basically happens whenever I initialize my database with the plugin, whenever I open it
After that error, subsequent calls to my database fail with the same error:
Error: Run: ExecSet: in saveToStore SetDBToStore: undefined
Error: Query: <database-name> database not opened
So far I only noticed this bug on the web but for sure it's possible that it happens on native too since I am looking into the console less there and I am also not refreshing the page there at all, compared to when developing on the web.
So my quetion basically is, what the cause of this error could be, that undefined is returned.
It has sth to do with the jeepSqliteElement I think, since when looking at the source of SetDBToStore:
static async setDBToStore(mDb, dbName, store) {
    try {
        // export the database
        const data = mDb.export();
        // store the database
        await UtilsStore.saveDBToStore(dbName, data, store);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(`SetDBToStore: ${err.message}`);
    }
}

I am calling the saveToStore method on the web too, mentioned here:
https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/issues/545
I know this might seem like neglible but the app completely breaks for the user every 1/100 refreshes, which might also prevent users from staying on the page in the first place.

Old answer is not yet an accepted answer!
This question is still not answered and I am still looking for some advice.
While the old answer prevented this bug from occuring on app startup, this bug still occurs sometimes in my app, way after it has started up. I saw it occuring mostly when LOTS of data is inserted/deleted so far.
Old answer:
I solved it with a rather ugly but effective fix:
the error occured in my downloadUserData method, see below here:
previous code:
await firstValueFrom(this.createInitialDataService.isDatabaseInit$.pipe(filter(Boolean)));
this.dataSyncService.downloadUserData(activeTurbo).pipe(first()).subscribe();

code that fixes it, by adding a 100ms timeout:
await firstValueFrom(this.createInitialDataService.isDatabaseInit$.pipe(filter(Boolean)));
setTimeout(() => {this.dataSyncService.downloadUserData(activeTurbo).pipe(first()).subscribe(); 
}, 100); // give the app some time to breathe to prevent the infamous bug

